# Way to add xml root element annotation for generated class?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, wsdl

I have generated JAXB classes from WSDL file, and what I'm trying to do is to convert XML to Java object. Here is generated JAXB class example:

```
XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "GetProductListResponse", propOrder = {
    "productList",
    "productListDate",
    "failed",
    "failedDescription"
})
public class GetProductListResponse {

@XmlElementRef(name = "ProductList", namespace = "http://productService.productsdata", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
protected JAXBElement<ArrayOfProductListDetail> productList;
@XmlElementRef(name = "ProductListDate", namespace = "http://productService.productsdata", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
protected JAXBElement<String> productListDate;
@XmlElement(name = "Failed")
protected boolean failed;
@XmlElement(name = "FailedDescription", required = true, nillable = true)
protected String failedDescription;

...
}
```

Example of XML that I need to convert to `GetProductListResponse` object is stored inside the `products.xml` file, and it looks like this:

```
<GetProductListResult xmlns="http://productService.productsdata">
            <ProductList>
               <ProductListDetail>
                  <ProductName>SomeProductName</ProductName>
                  <ProductCost>9,45</ProductCost>
               </ProductListDetail>
               <ProductListDate>09.09.2015</ProductListDate>
               <Failed>false</Failed>
               <FailedDescription/>
            </ProductList>
</GetProductListResult>
```

Inside the `convertXmlProductsTest` method is where the conversion call is set - using `jaxb unmarshaller` for that purpose:

```
public class ProductHandler {

    public static GetProductListResponse convertXmlProductsTest(){
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(GetProductListResponse.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            GetProductListResponse retval = (GetProductListResponse) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("products.xml"));

            return retval;
        } catch (JAXBException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ProductMockWs.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("XML to Java object conversion failed.");
    }
}
```

The problem is that generated JAXB class `GetProductListResponse` does not contain `@XmlRootElement` annotation, so this conversion fails with the famous error message `javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element ... Expected elements are ...`.

When I manually add `@XmlRootElement` annotation to the `GetProductListResponse` class, and set it as:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="GetProductsListResult")
public class GetProductListResponse { ...}
```

conversion succeeds.

**QUESTION:**
Is there any way to set `@XmlRootElement` for generated class (`GetProductListResponse` ) from outside that class?

I want to avoid customization of generated class and I don't want to change WSDL definition. Also I read about setting the runtime annotations but I would like to avoid the need to use any Java bytecode manipulators (like Javassist).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(GetProductListResponse.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

    JAXBElement<GetProductListResponse> root = jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(
            file), GetProductListResponse.class);
    GetProductListResponse productListResponse = root.getValue();
```

For missing @XmlRootElement this article helped me a lot. Take a look :

http://www.source4code.info/2013/07/jaxb-marshal-unmarshal-with-missing.html

You can find your error here and see what you can do! Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in [Jackson json/xml parser library](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome).  Jackson [fully supports JAXB annotations](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJAXBAnnotations) and its [mixin feature](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations) allows you to add annotations to a Class externally from its source.

Comment: Thanks  for response @sharonbn! I tried Jackson library as you suggested but I'm having trouble to parse the XML because some of the generated classes does not have setters or no-arg constructor generated (i.e. ArrayOfProductListDetail). I also tried to use jaxb annotate plugin with maven and to add binding jxb file, but the xsd files are badly written, so the maven-jaxb2-compiler complains a lot - referencing on about hundreds of places inside the xsd files with collision errors reported. Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry, dont have any other suggestions.